# what is this double arrow in a circle symbol means?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, current-source

Here is the symbol:
(a double arrowhead with a single tail enclosed in a circle)

[image]

Here is the full circuit diagram for context.

[image]

My guess is this is an ideal current source symbol, as shown here but I'm not sure.
https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Ideal_current_source_symbols.svg

Comment: Yes, it looks like an ideal current.